# for in range no flask template

Tags: python-3.x, for, template, flask

Estou com dúvida,  a API que estou pegando me retorna dois tipo de dados "ID" e "Title" são várias id e title e queria joga isso na minha tabela num "for" template. Queria saber se o que eu fiz está certo pois  ele não me retorna nada.

código no flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def game():
    url = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    resp = json.loads(url.text)
    return resp

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data = game())



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

É o template:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minha pagina</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste de API</h1>
    <br>

    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td align= middle width=100 bgcolor= #DAA520> ID </td>
            <td align= middle width=100 bgcolor= #DAA520> TITLE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {% for i in range(3) %}
            <td align= middle width=150>{{resp[i] ["id"]}}</td>
            <td align= middle width=150>{{resp[i]["title"]}}</td>
        {% endfor %}

        </tr>

    </table>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`resp`não está definido, é `data`

```
{% for i in range(3) %}
    <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i] ["id"]}}</td>
    <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i]["title"]}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não tem retorno dos dados em seu template porque está usando o nome da variável errado. Ao invés de `resp`, você deve usar `data`, o mesmo nome que você usou para passar os dados no retorno da função `index`.

Uma sugestão: Por uma questão de legibilidade, normalmente quando preciso usar algum tipo de iteração nos templates, faço isso de forma explícita, ou seja, considerando que `data` provavelmente é uma lista de dicionários, eu escreveria o seu código da seguinte forma:

```
{% for element in data %}
    <td>{{ element["id"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ element["title"] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Por experiência própria, facilita muito escrever o código da forma mais legível possível. Depois de algum tempo sem ver o código ilegível, ao voltar a escrever sobre ele, nem parece que foi você mesmo que escreveu de tão confuso que é tentar entender novamente o seu próprio código, e isso consome muito tempo.

Recomendo também adicionar atributos aos elementos HTML utilizando CSS para estilo (align="middle"...) ou Javascript para qualquer outro atributo que você queira.